# Группировка json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, яндекс-карты

Не могли бы подсказать. У меня несколько вопросов. 
Кратко опишу задачу. Есть координаты в json. Есть отдельно список с адресами. Есть карта. Как соотнести адреса с точками на карте, чтобы при клике на "ссылку" открывалась конкретная точка?

Есть файл json. Взят из [примера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/1.1/object_manager)

Структура вида:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
```

]}

```
    ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10,
            maxAnimationZoomDifference: 50,
            controls: []
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

    // Создадим пользовательский макет ползунка масштаба.
    ZoomLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass("<div>" +
        "<div id='zoom-in' class='btn'><i class='icon-plus'></i></div><br>" +
        "<div id='zoom-out' class='btn'><i class='icon-minus'></i></div>" +
        "</div>", {

        // Переопределяем методы макета, чтобы выполнять дополнительные действия
        // при построении и очистке макета.
        build: function () {
            // Вызываем родительский метод build.
            ZoomLayout.superclass.build.call(this);

            // Привязываем функции-обработчики к контексту и сохраняем ссылки
            // на них, чтобы потом отписаться от событий.
            this.zoomInCallback = ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomIn, this);
            this.zoomOutCallback = ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomOut, this);

            // Начинаем слушать клики на кнопках макета.
            $('#zoom-in').bind('click', this.zoomInCallback);
            $('#zoom-out').bind('click', this.zoomOutCallback);
        },

        clear: function () {
            // Снимаем обработчики кликов.
            $('#zoom-in').unbind('click', this.zoomInCallback);
            $('#zoom-out').unbind('click', this.zoomOutCallback);

            // Вызываем родительский метод clear.
            ZoomLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
        },

        zoomIn: function () {
            var map = this.getData().control.getMap();
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1, {checkZoomRange: true});
        },

        zoomOut: function () {
            var map = this.getData().control.getMap();
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1, {checkZoomRange: true});
        }
    }),
    zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({options: {layout: ZoomLayout}});

    myMap.controls.add(zoomControl);


    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: false,
        gridSize: 32
    });



    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set({
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'img/svg/point.svg',
        iconImageSize: [30, 42],
        iconImageOffset: [-3, -42]
    });    

myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

$.ajax({
    url: "js/data.json"
}).done(function(data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задаем data-id для каждого пункта. Id уже проставлены.
А потом просто:

```
$('span.show-on-the-map').click(function() { 
    $ids = $(this).parent().parent('.wherebuy__list__item').data('id'); // получаем data id
    objectManager.objects.balloon.open($ids); // показываем на карте
    $('.wherebuy__map').addClass('active'); //показываем карту
});
```